# How to use generator interface in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i want use the interface Generator.

```
interface Generator<T = unknown, TReturn = any, TNext = unknown> extends Iterator<T, TReturn, TNext> .
```

but how to implements it?
i dont know how to impl return throw and Symbol.iterator.

```
class MyGenerator implements Generator{
    next(...args: [] | [unknown]): IteratorResult<unknown, any> {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    return(value: any): IteratorResult<unknown, any> {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    throw(e: any): IteratorResult<unknown, any> {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
    [Symbol.iterator](): Generator<unknown, any, unknown> {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}
```

can give me some example code?
thanks for help!

i dont know how to impl return throw and Symbol.iterator.